# Can I make a regular Windows 7 installation into a VirtualBox VM?

Tags: windows-7, macos, virtualbox, virtual-machine

On my mac I am running Windows 7 in bootcamp. It works really well, but I would be interested in running Windows as a VM instead in virtualbox. I could of course just re-install, but it would be slicker to just make a VM out of the existing partition instead. Is that possible?

Comment: There are tools to go from a physical machine to a virtual machine all one has to do is do a Google search.  What tools have you tried?

Comment: @Ramhound None so far

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx here you go since the answer is a link feel free to answer this question yourself

Comment: If you make it an answer I can select it as the correct answer...